# In EHCache, how to prevent elements to be added to the cache?

Tags: java, ehcache

I am creating an EHCache instance like this:

```
CacheManager cacheMgr = CacheManager.getInstance();
cacheMgr.setName("myCache");

CacheConfiguration cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration(getCacheName(), 1)                  
                    .eternal(true)
                    .overflowToOffHeap(false)
                    .timeToLiveSeconds(0)
                    .maxEntriesLocalHeap(1)
                    .timeToIdleSeconds(0) .diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds(0);

Cache merchantCache = new Cache(cacheConfig);
cacheMgr.addCache(merchantCache);

merchantCache.put(new Element("key", "value"));
merchantCache.put(new Element("key1", "value"));
merchantCache.put(new Element("key2", "value"));
```

Running this code, I do not get any exception. Because I created the Cache with `maxEntriesLocalHeap` = 1, I was hoping to get an exception, because I put three elements there.

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use `maxEntriesInCache` instead of `maxEntriesLocalHeap` as per: http://ehcache.org/apidocs/net/sf/ehcache/config/CacheConfiguration.html#maxEntriesInCache

**EDIT:** For non-clustered ehcache use: `maxElementsInMemory`

Comment: fyi, maxEntriesInCache is not applicable to unclustered caches (which per his configuration it seems like he's using)

Comment: @lanimall: Oh I didn't know that. Is `maxElementsInMemory` applicable for OP's case?

Comment: maxElementsInMemory will indeed put a limit on the number of items, but will not stop you to add more entries if you want to...(which is I believe the question asked here). What will happen is some non-expired cached entries will be evicted to make space to the new entries you're trying to add (per my answer)

Answer (score 0):

you're not doing anything wrong...Please check the memory eviction policies described at:
http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/storage-options#memory-use-spooling-and-expiry-strategy

By default (if memoryStoreEvictionPolicy is not specified), LRU (Last recently used) policy is used...meaning that if there is no more space in your cache, the oldest-hit element will be evicted to make room for the new elements you're trying to put into your cache.

So with your specific test/code, the key you have in cache at the end is likely "key2" per eviction policy..."key" was evicted when you entered "key1", and "key1" was evicted when you entered "key2".

Frankly, I'm not sure why you would need to put a hard limit on cache entries that way...instead of letting them recycle naturally (maybe change the eviction policy to use LFU - Last frequently used - so you get over time the hotset of your cache entries in memory...

If you were using a clustered cache with BigMemory Max (http://terracotta.org/products/bigmemorymax), you could put a hard limit using "maxEntriesInCache" (this is only valid for clustered caches)